# Span label doesn't treat pressed Enter button as new line when returned

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a custom `span` label with the role of `textarea` where I expect to enter multi-line text into it.

```css
  .input,
.textarea {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  padding: 5px 50px;
}


.textarea {
  display: block;
  width: 1000px;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: none;
  min-height: 200px;
  line-height: 20px;
white-space: pre-wrap;
}

.textarea[contenteditable]:empty::before {
  content: "Mail Body Template";
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<p><span id="mail_body_template" oninput="generate(this.value)" class="textarea" role="textbox" contenteditable></span></p>
```

However, when I print the read value of the `textarea`, it appears it doesn't create new lines on pressing `Enter` but can do so only with `Shift+Enter`.

I tried to add a `onpresskey` listener on the `span` to catch the `Enter` and create a new line but it never works.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#mail_body_template').on('keypress',function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        $('#mail_body_template').val($('#mail_body_template').val() + "\r\n");
    }
});
```

[image]
[image]

Ultimately, I want to be able to let the `span` treat `Enter` as a new line same as it does with `Shift+Enter`.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

the content of a contentEditable is HTML.
using .val() or .value doesn't return the content of the span.

It is not a console line. You cannot use \r or \n to force a line break.

You can however insert a `<br>` tag and this should allow the line break.

in order to access the value, you should use innerHTML.

your code is missing the generate function to further get where the error might be located. (The fact that you bind a keypress / Keydown event on the span also might trigger some weird behaviour we might not be able to reproduce.

```
function generate(myVal){
        console.log("this.value : "+myVal)
    console.log("jqueryVal : "+$("#mail_body_template").val());
    console.log("innerHtml : "+document.getElementById("mail_body_template").innerHTML);
    console.log("jqueryHtml : "+$("#mail_body_template").html());
    console.log("plainText : "+$("#mail_body_template").text());
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kezqs7tv/5/

Here is a js.fiddle snippet that shows what I mean.

Comment: Also even though it might not be clear from my answer but the enter key in a content editable adds a br tag to the html and not a "newline"